# PHP - getting data from sql database

Tags: php, sql

I am having a problem getting the data from my sql database using session's. I am trying to make a log-in system. I already have this working but every use gets directed to the same page - I want private profiles on it that can only be viewed by the person logging in with the correct email address and password.

I am using the following code - I am getting an error on line 19! If I'm honest I dont 100% understand this line - I am new to PHP and SQL and have been reading up about all of this but not getting an answer that fully explains it to me.

Any help would be appreciated - referring me to a tutorial any thing...

```
<?php # DISPLAY COMPLETE FORUM PAGE.

# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) ) { require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; }

# Set page title and display header section.
$page_title = 'Forum' ;


# Open database connection.
require ( 'connect_db.php' ) ;

# Display body section, retrieving from 'forum' database table.
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $_SESSION[email]" ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users"))
{
  echo '<table><tr><th></th><th></th><th id="msg"></th></tr>';
  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
  {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['first_name'] .' '. $row['last_name'] . '<br>'.        $row['email'].'</td>
    <td>','</td><td>','</td> </tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>' ;
}
else { echo '<p>There are currently no messages.</p>' ; }

# Create navigation links.
#echo '<p><a href="post.php">Post Message</a> | <a href="shop.php">Shop</a> | <a     href="home.php">Home</a> | <a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a></p>' ;

# Close database connection.
mysqli_close( $dbc ) ;



?>
```

Comment: Whats the error you're getting say?

Comment: Did you connect to the database properly?
Note: It was not necessary to provide all this code.

Comment: @Tom11 It was necessary, so we can see it in its entirety to debug. If he didn't, we'd just be asking to see it anyway.

Comment: "I am getting an error on line 19!". What is on line 19 in above code?

Comment: THank all - line 19 is:if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users"))

Comment: What is the meaning of storing query result on line 19? `$result`. Because you're executing just above it and store in `$r`. The what is the purpose of query at line 19?

Comment: Hi all - Thanks for the help with this - this is the last part i need to get working to complete the background bits of my site. The last problem I have is with line 19:   if ($result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users"))     - does anyone have any advise on this please? Thanks -Tom.

Comment: This is actually the faulty line - sorry!!!!   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))

Answer (score 2):

you have a syntax error in your session:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $_SESSION[email]" ;
```

Change it to:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['email']}" ;
```

But you should also escape your session data prior to inserting it into the database.

In addition, the text in your `while()` loop has another syntax error:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $row['first_name'] .' '. $row['last_name'] . '<br>'.        $row['email'].'</td>
<td>','</td><td>','</td> </tr>';
```

Remove the commas, replace them with periods:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $row['first_name'] .' '. $row['last_name'] . '<br>'. $row['email'].'</td> <td>' . '</td><td>' . '</td> </tr>';
```

By like @gareth said, you should probably choose either prodedural or object-oriented style of coding and stick with it, IE, either use `mysqli_query()` or `$mysql->query()` :)

Comment: Thanks Phil for the quick response - I have made the changes that you suggested but the error then changes to the code:    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['email']" ;

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\pic\001\forum.php on line 17

Comment: I've updated my answer, and tested it. I got the same error as you, but not in the revised code. You need to add curly braces around `$_SESSION['email']`, so it should now look like `WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['email']}`

Comment: Rather than escaping the session data, he should be using parametrized queries.  http://bobby-tables.com/php shows how.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide if you're using `mysqli` in procedural style (like in the first line of this extract) or in object oriented style (like in the second line).

```
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users"))
{
```

Looking at the rest of your posted code, I'd imagine that changing the second line (your line 19) to `if ($result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users"))` will get rid of that error (though not necessarily any other errors).

Comment: i GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR ON THIS LINE NOW:  Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\pic\001\forum.php on line 19

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry, I normally use the OO version. You'll need to add in your `$dbc` first like this: `($result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM users"))`

Answer (score 0):

You say "*I am getting an error on line 19!* " - Is the line wrap that you have above which shows line 20 starting with no quote mark and a td actually in your code?  If so remove the line break and ensure that line 19 continues right through the rest of the table row to the ";"

Comment: Line 19 is -  if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users"))

Comment: Oops - You had no line numbers showing and I obviously miscounted when I tried to find your error.

Comment: You can actually include newlines in strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '". $_SESSION['email']. "'";
```

**Edit:**

As you're comparing `email` it means it should be string so you need to wrap it in quotes like above.

Try also with

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM users"))
```

See that either user Procedure way or OOPs way. Try with above by adding `$dbc` to `mysqli_query()`